# force position of figure in beamer class

Tags: beamer, floats

My latex code for the frame with the problematic image. `Text` is always just one line of text and the equations `3-5` leave enough space on the right to squeeze a figure for explanation on the lower right part of the frame. I tried to work with `wrapfigure`, without success, as there appear to be multiple problems with the beamer class?! After that I tried to manually squeeze it in using `hspace` and `vspace`, with and without `*` right after `\begin{figure}` . This brought me a bit further, but not to the desired result as at some point the whole text of the frame is moving and disappears below the lower border, when changing the value for `vspace`. Here is an illustration of my code snippet:

```
\begin{frame}
\textbf{Headline}\\
Text
$$equation.$$


\visible<2->{\textbf{2nd Headline}\\
Text
$$2nd equation$$}


\visible<3->{\textbf{3rd Headline}\\
Text,\\
Text
$$3rd equation,$$
where
$$4th equation$$
defines
$$5th equation$$
Text.
\begin{figure}
\centering
\vspace*{-4.5cm}
\hspace*{8.6cm}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Pics/explanation.pdf}
\end{figure}
}
\end{frame}
```

Is there a way to "freely" move the figure, without changing the layout of the rest of the frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a good case for the 'picture' environment. By adjusting the values of `230,50` you can move it to the exact position you want.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \textbf{Headline}

    Text
    \[
        equation.
    \]

    \visible<2->{%

        \textbf{2nd Headline}

        Text
        \[
            2nd equation
        \]
    }

    \visible<3->{%

        \textbf{3rd Headline}

        Text,

        Text
        \[
            3rd equation,
        \]
        where
        \[
            4th equation
        \]
        defines
        \[
            5th equation
        \]
        Text.

        \begin{picture}(0,0)
            \put(230,50){%
                \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}%
            }
        \end{picture}
    }
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! This is what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [columns environment](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Presentations#Columns) to split your slide into multiple columns. Your slide could look like this:

```
\begin{frame}
\textbf{Headline}\\
Text
$$equation.$$


\visible<2->{\textbf{2nd Headline}\\
Text 
$$2nd equation$$


\visible<3->{\textbf{3rd Headline}\\
\begin{columns}
\column{.5\textwidth}
Text,\\
Text
$$3nd equation,$$
where
$$4nd equation$$
defines
$$5nd equation$$
Text.
\column{.5\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Pics/explanation.pdf}
\end{figure}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: I took the liberty re replace "package" by "environment", as the first might give the impression one would need to load an additional package. Please feel free to roll back, if you disagree.

Comment: I actually don't want to split this part in x%/(1-x%) for text and image. Furthermore, if I use `\column{\textwidth}` for the first column and comment the second column, then it moves the `Text` and `equation` part downwards, s.t. not everything can be read.
I just would like to "squeeze" the image in the resulting white space on the right without changing the layout of the left. Is there no "hack"/"trick" to fulfil this?