# Make latex presentation with complex animation

Tags: beamer

I would like to make presentation in beamer with the below desired output:
[image: Desired output]

There is no MWE as I cannot figure out how to do this. Help me out...

Edit 1: I would also like to have a caption for this figure. Also, is it possible to do this kind of animation with equation too?

Comment: it's really ok that you were not able to do it. Atleast it would be nice if you can show us what you have tried so far. Because, please do note that this is not a `just-do-it-me` site. Moreover, -1 for no MWE. I will be happy to upvote it as soon as you show us what you have tried :)

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119788/overlay-multiline-text-in-the-image-in-beamer/119795, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32661/how-to-locate-figures-with-x-y-specified-location-in-a-presentation, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319710/force-position-of-figure-in-beamer-classgu, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244123/interactive-beamer-presentation-with-clicks-and-arrows/244132 etc.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks you for the help suggested...

Comment: If you have a new question about how to add a caption, please ask a NEW question. Neither comments nor edits are a good place for new questions

Answer (score 3):

A short example to give you something to start with:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}};
\node[visible on=<2>] (a) at (4,-2) {text};
\draw[<-,red,visible on=<2>] (0,1) -- (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot again looking at my issue and giving me a starting point. But, could you please let me know how the co-ordinates (4,-2) & (0,1) are assigned?

Comment: @sreerajt They give the position of the text and the end point of the arrow (the other site of the arrow will automatically start at the position of the text, which is named `(a)`). I just randomly used some coordinated to demonstrate the mechanism, adjust them to whatever you need for your real image.

Comment: Thank you for the reply..

Comment: How to give caption to this figure? I could not do it in usual way, so I modified the code like this:

\end{tikzpicture}
{\center Caption}

Also, is it possible to do this with equation? I wrote a code  \begin{frame}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \node{
  \begin{equation*}
  (A-B)(C-D)\left[1-\frac{E}{F}\right]=0
  \end{equation*}};
 \node[visible on=<2>] (a) at (4.5,-2.5) {$\Omega_H=0.65$Hz};
 \draw[<-,red,visible on=<2>] (1.0,-0.4) -- (a);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{frame}
I am getting error message "Missing $ inserted. \end{frame}".

Comment: @sreerajt If you have new questions, please use the "Ask question" button on the top right

Comment: thank you for pointing out the "Ask question" button which is located on top of page. I knew that and it was through that I asked question till now. I have edited the question. If possible kindly help me out..